# Find an argument for complex number $ \frac{1}{(1+2wi)^2} $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Let $ w $ be a real number. Find an argument for

$$ \frac{1}{(1+2wi)^2} $$

Answer should be $ -2\arctan(2w) $. I keep getting $\arctan\left(\frac{-4w}{1+4w^2}\right) $ as an answer.

My steps involved multiplying both denominator and numerator with the conjugate of the denominator squared, which eventually led me to the answer above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\operatorname{arg}(z^m)=m\cdot\operatorname{arg}(z)+k\pi$ where integer $k$ such that $\operatorname{arg}(z^m)$ remains in $\in(-\pi,\pi]$

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) for the definition of arg$(x+iy)$

Here $\operatorname{arg}(1+2wi)^{-2}=(-2)\operatorname{arg}(1+2wi)+\pi$

$$\operatorname{arg}(1+2wi)=\arctan(2w)$$

Comment: shouldn't $\arg(z^m) \in ]-\pi, \pi]$?

Comment: @dietervdf, Thanks for your feedback. That was for $\arctan(x)$

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea $ (z^m)=m\cdot (z)+k\pi $. I need to read up on it!

Comment: @user1904218 Easy proof: $z = re^{i\theta}$, then $z^m = r^m e^{im\theta}$, thus $\arg z^m = m\theta +2k\pi = m\arg{z} + 2k\pi$. With $k$ such that $m\theta +2k\pi \in {]-\pi, \pi]}$ (I think it should be $\color{red}{2}k\pi$ instead of $k\pi$ ;) )

Comment: Where does pi*arg(1+2wi) come from?

Comment: @Dasherman, Where do you see $pi*$?

Comment: I misread, sorry.